# Accessing data attribute using jquery returns undefined?

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

Inside my view i have a button as follow:

```
<button data-assigned-id="@IdUser" onclick="updateClick()" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default"></button>
```

My div

```
<div id="partial_load_div">

</div>
```

Script

```
function updateClick() {
    var id = $(this).data('assigned-id');
    $('#partial_load_div').show();
    $('#partial_load_div').load('/Users/UpdatePartial?id=' + id);
}
```

The id is always shows as undefined, i checked and `@IdUser` has always value

then in chrome dev i got the error

**GET http://localhost:19058/Users/UpdatePartial?id=undefined 400 (Bad Request)**

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Delete `onclick="updateClick()" ` and add a class name or id for use a a selector and then `$('#mybutton').click( function) { var id = $(this).data('assigned-id'); ....`

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for your comment, that works fine!
could you add your comment into an answer so that i can mark it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your current script, `$(this)` refers to the `Window` object (not your button) which does not have a `data-` attribute so its `undefined`.

You could solve this by passing the element to the function

```
<button data-assigned-id="@IdUser" onclick="updateClick(this)" type="button" ... ></button>
```

```js
function updateClick(element) {
    var id = $(element).data('assigned-id');
    ....
```

However a better approach is to use [Unobtrusive Javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) rather than polluting your markup with behavior.

```
<button data-assigned-id="@IdUser" id="mybutton" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default"></button>
```

```js
$('#mybutton').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data('assigned-id'); // $(this) refers to the button
    ....
});
```

Comment: Any idea how to fix **Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience**  when i apply this script?

Comment: That error wont happen because of the code in my answer. My best guess is that your `.load()` is loading a partial view that has script tag in it (if so, remove it - partials should never have scripts)

Comment: I have the follwoing scripts in my partial
**<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>**
and
**<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>** i think those are important for validation since my partial view is a form

Comment: You definitely need to remove those from your partial. Move them into the main view (or layout)

Comment: and my validation will still work? ok will give it a try thanks a lot

Comment: And because you dynamically loading content that contains a form that you want to validate, you need to reparse the validator in the success callback of the `.load()` event. Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31768946/required-field-validations-not-working-in-jquery-popup-mvc-4/31769058#31769058)

Answer (score 18):

When reading data attributes using `data()` you need to remove the `-` and **camel case the value**. So you want:

```
var id = $(this).data('assignedId');
```

the [docs on data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5) show this:

> As of jQuery 1.4.3 HTML 5 data- attributes will be automatically
>   pulled in to jQuery's data object. The treatment of attributes with
>   embedded dashes was changed in jQuery 1.6 to conform to the W3C HTML5
>   specification.
>
> For example, given the following HTML:
>
> ```
> <div data-role="page" data-last-value="43" data-hidden="true" data-options='{"name":"John"}'></div>
> ```
>
> All of the following jQuery code will work.
>
> ```
> $( "div" ).data( "role" ) === "page";
> $( "div" ).data( "lastValue" ) === 43;
> $( "div" ).data( "hidden" ) === true;
> $( "div" ).data( "options" ).name === "John";
> ```
>
> The second statement of the code above correctly refers to the
>   data-last-value attribute of the element. In case no data is stored
>   with the passed key, jQuery searches among the attributes of the
>   element, converting a camel-cased string into a dashed string and then
>   prepending data- to the result. So, the string lastValue is converted
>   to data-last-value.

---

I didn't notice how your binding the click event. If you want to use `$(this)` you have to bind the event using jquery. So you need:

```
<button data-assigned-id="works" id="button">
clickme</button>

$(window).ready(function() {
     //bind the event using jquery not the onclick attribute of the button
     $('#button').on('click', updateClick);

});


function updateClick() {
    alert($(this).data('assignedId'));
}
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tq3hg5e4/)

Comment: thanks for taking the time answering my question! I'm still getting the same error. i don't know why doesn't work

Comment: I didn't notice another issue you had @Maro. See update

Comment: They just strip the dashes and store the keys in all-lowercase. You have to use a case-insensitive lookup in order to get anything that you actually camel-cased in your HTML. Worst specification ever, but thanks for pointing it out, I never would have guessed.

Answer (score 3):

As far as my usage was concerned, even though the attribute was data-assignedId (Camel cased), when retrieving it you would have to use data('assignedid').  Using camel casing returned undefined.