# Form Validation Bootbox

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, bootbox

I'm displaying a `PartialView` in a `Bootbox` from another `PartialView`. Then the data of `PartialView` will be saved in a database. Now, before saving it to the database, I need to assure that all required fields have a correct values (E.g. Not empty).

Please find below codes.

**Partial View to display in Bootbox (dialog)**

```
@model WebSensoryMvc.Models.SampleData

 @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "SessionData", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "FormCreateSample", name = "FormCreateSample" }))
 {
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="container">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GroupNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.GroupNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GroupNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MaterialID, "Material", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("MaterialID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MaterialID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SampleCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SampleCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SampleCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BatchCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BatchCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BatchCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SizeID, "Size", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("SizeID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SizeID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AgeID, "Age", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("AgeID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AgeID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TemperatureID, "Temperature", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("TemperatureID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TemperatureID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PackagingTypeID, "Packaging Type", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("PackagingTypeID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PackagingTypeID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Spike, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Spike)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Spike, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SampleType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SampleType, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SampleType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Remarks, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Remarks, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Remarks, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        @*<div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>*@
    </div>
</div>
```

}

**Script to show the Bootbox with PartialView**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#modalCreateSample").on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/SessionData/Create",
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {

                bootbox.dialog({
                    title: "Create Session",
                    message: data,
                    buttons: {
                        success: {
                            label: "Save",
                            className: "btn-success",
                            callback: function () {

                                $.ajax({
                                    url: "/SessionData/Create",
                                    data: $("#FormCreateSample").serialize(),
                                    type: "POST",
                                    success: function (data) {
                                        alert('success');

                                        return true;
                                    },
                                    error: function (error) {
                                        alert('error');

                                        return false;
                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("Error: Please try again.");
            }
        });
    });
});
 </script>
```

Below is the sample snip of my current page so far. Once the user click the **Save** button it should fire a validation in the display popup.

My problem now is on how to implement a **validation** in a `PartialView` and `Bootbox`? Any suggestion? TIA

[image]

**************************** Update #1 ****************************
I ended up using the `Bootstrap Modal` rather than using `Bootbox`. I can now validate my form using the code gave by @Stephen Muecke.

I'm just having a follow up regarding this. When calling my `POST` method the `serialize()` method return empty? Using my old piece of code return the correct `serialize()` data.

Comment: Is your partial form loaded dynamically (i.e. using ajax after the initial page has been rendered)? If so, you need to reparse the validator

Comment: Hi, actually it is being loaded using jQuery. If you can see the above script. By firing the click event of #modalCreateSample. How do I reparse the Validator? Can you cite an example? TIA

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31768946/required-field-validations-not-working-in-jquery-popup-mvc-4/31769058#31769058) shows how to reparse the validator after the form has been added to the view. I am not familiar with bootbox so I am not sure what events there are to plug into once the DOM has been updated (but looking at the docs, there don't appear to be any)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke

Thanks for the link. I will check and try this.

Comment: There is an [init function](http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html#bb-method-init) that can be called on a Bootbox object, which will be called when the modal is created. There isn't anything built into Bootbox to respond to internal markup changes - the alert, confirm, and prompt dialogs attempt to match the native dialogs (which don't currently have events), and the custom dialog assumes you're handling everything. I would assume the process in the linked answer is the simplest way to handle DOM updates in the modal.