# Validation for multiple partial views not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view with **Tuple model**. I'm loading 4 partial views in this main view as below

1.

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" > 
   @Html.Partial("~/Views/Partial/_Tab1Input.cshtml", Model.Item1.Tab1Input)
</div>
```

2.

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="_Pump">   
  @Html.Partial("~/Views/Partial/_Tab2Input.cshtml", Model.Item1.Tab2Input)
</div>
```

3.

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" >
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Partial/_Tab3Input.cshtml", Model.Item1.Tab3Input)  
 </div>
```

4.

```
<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="_TDH">  
  @Html.Partial("~/Views/Partial/_Tab4Input.cshtml", Model.Item1.Tab4Input) 
</div>
```

I'm loading these partial views on tab click. On click of submit, only active Tab is getting validated. Means if I'm in tab 2 partial view and clicked on submit, then required field validation will happen, but tab 1 partial view's validation will be ignored, and the form is **getting Posted**.

Please assist me so that ***on click of submit, all 4 partial views required field validation should happen***.

Comment: how are you doing the current validation? Can you provide some code?

Comment: You need to re-parse the`$. validator` is you adding dynamic content

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Required field validations not working in JQuery Popup MVC 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31768946/required-field-validations-not-working-in-jquery-popup-mvc-4)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke   - In the main view I have input type as submit, which is validating only active tab and submitting the form.  ValidationMessageFor also is definded for each input and in model also [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")] is provided. Why only active tab is getting validated i'm not getting.

Comment: Read the duplicate! The other 3 tabs are loaded after the view has been rendered (_I'm loading these partial views on tab click_) so you need to re-parse the validator

Comment: Hi Stephen...I have input type as submit, and dont have button click event for this. Please assist me where I need to put these lines of code.                               
var form = $('form');
    form.data('validator', null);
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);

Do i need to put at document.ready of other 3 tabs.
Please assist