# HttpPostedFileBase postedFile is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I had a Ajax.BeginForm to do a upload of a file.It´s all right except when I debug my controller the parameter HttpPostedFileBase postedFile is null.

```html
 <div class="form-group">
            <input type="file" class="form-control" name="postedFile" id="postedFile" />
            <input type="submit" value="Import" />
        </div>
```

```
 public JsonResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase postedFile)
```

My Ajax.BeginForm

```html
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("UploadFile", "Ponto", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    OnSuccess = "OnSuccess",
    OnFailure = "OnFailure",
    LoadingElementId = "progress"
    
}, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

the 
has the same name on parameter controller.

Comment: No, it does not have the same name as the controller parameter.  `file` is not the same thing as `postedFile`.

Comment: I realized that when I got rid <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script> works perfectly, but don´t show up the loader.

Comment: You cannot upload files using `Ajax.BeginForm()`. Use `jQuery.ajax()` with `FormData`.

Comment: Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31768946/required-field-validations-not-working-in-jquery-popup-mvc-4/31769058#31769058) for an example