# How do I correctly use EditorFor to display checkbox selections from an AJAX call, and POST the selections?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-binding, editorfor

My question is two-fold.

I have a View that gets data on the change of a drop down selection.

The data retrieved is a List property of a ViewModel class using an Ajax call.

This data is shown as a selection of check boxes for the user to select any number of them.

If I return a Partial View from an AJAX call, this is easy enough, but from what I have experienced, this doesn't work for POST'ing back to the controller. Nothing is bound correctly.

From what I have read the correct way is to use EditorFor, So firstly, I cannot figure out how to populate the EditorFor from the AJAX call.

Secondly, If I test by sending initial data from my GET, the EditorFor displays the correct checkbox options, but when I POST, the count of the items is 0.

View:

```
@model EngineeringAssistantMVC.Controllers.FirmwareController.FirmwareViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Firmware", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "uploadFirmwareForm", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{

    <!-- Device -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-1">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Device, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
         </div>

         <div class="col-lg-2">
             @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Device, ViewBag.Devices as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "Devices" })
         </div>

         <div class="col-lg-9">
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Device, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
         </div>
     </div>

    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.SelectedModels, "SelectedModels", new { @id = "Models" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.SelectedModels)

}
```

And the AJAX call:

```
function GetModels() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '@Url.Action("GetModels", "Firmware", null)',
        data: { SelectedDevice: $('#Devices').val() },
        success: function (dataSet) {

            //$('#Models').html(dataSet);
            //$('#Models').data(dataSet);
            //$('#Models').val(dataSet);                

            // How do I populate the EditorFor from the dataSet returned?
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log("ERROR: " + err.responseText);
        },
    })
}
```

SelectedModels EditFor Template:

```
@model IEnumerable<EngineeringAssistantMVC.ViewModels.ModelViewModel>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => item.IsSelected)
    @Html.Label(item.Description)

    @Html.HiddenFor(x => item.ModelId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => item.IsSelected)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => item.Description)
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile, FirmwareViewModel firmwareViewModel)
{
    // firmwareViewModel.SelectedModels count is 0 here
}
```

ModelFirmware Class:

```
public class ModelFirmware
{
    public int ModelFirmwareId { get; set; }
    public int FirmwareId { get; set; }
    public int ModelId { get; set; }
}
```

FirmwareViewModel:

```
public class FirmwareViewModel
{
    public int FirmwareViewModelId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Device { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ModelViewModel> SelectedModels { get; set; }
}
```

I just can't get it to work correctly.

EDIT 1: - Add method that returns the models

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetModels(string SelectedDevice)
    {
        var deviceAbbreviation = _dbContext.Radios.Where(x => x.RadioName == SelectedDevice).Select(x => x.ProjectAbbreviation).FirstOrDefault();
        var models = _dbContext.AnatomyModels.Where(x => x.SerialPrefix.StartsWith(deviceAbbreviation.Trim()) && x.ParentId == 0).ToList();

    List<ModelViewModel> mvms = models.Select(x => new ModelViewModel()
    {
        ModelId = x.AnatomyModelId,
        Description = x.SerialPrefix,
        IsSelected = false,
    }).ToList();

    return Json(mvms);
}
```

Comment: _this doesn't work for POST'ing back to the controller_ - that is because your code is wrong - but you have not shown that, or your ajax call or your `GetModels()` method, or what that returns, or how its being added to the DOM.

Comment: And what little you have shown is incorrect. The `EditorTempate` needs to be named `ModelViewModel.cshtml` (the same as the model, and located in the `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder, and in the view its just `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.SelectedModels)`. And you need to remove the `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.SelectedModels)`

Comment: And then the code in the `EditorTemplate` is `@model ModelViewModel` without the loop (the `EditorFor()` method correctly generates the html for each item in the collection, including the correct name attributes)

Comment: And since your using a view model. get rid of `ViewBag` and add a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` property for the dropdownlist, and a `HttpPostedFileBase` property for the uploaded file so that you can strongly bind to your model.

Comment: I have added the GetModel code. The ajax call code is shown above. That's one of my problems, I can't figure out how to add it to the DOM from the returned AJAX call. Will look at the other advice given so long. Thanks,

Comment: Why are your returning `json`? You should be returning a partial view based on `@model FirmwareViewModel` (but will only contain `EditorFor(m => m.SelectedModels)` and then you add the partial view in the ajax success callback - e.g. `$(someElement).html(dataSet);`

Comment: And you will also need to re-parse the validator if you want client side validation (refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31768946/required-field-validations-not-working-in-jquery-popup-mvc-4/31769058#31769058)

Comment: I am returning json because I tried returning a partial view which I couldn't get working and after much reading on Stack Overflow I thought I came to the conclusion that it couldn't be done that way? I guess that was an incorrect conclusion?

Comment: Give me 15 min and I'll add an answer explaining your issues and how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous issues with your code.

First your not using the `EditorTemplate` correctly. Change its name to `ModelViewModel.cshtml` to match the name of the class, and locate it in the `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` (or `/Views/YourControllerName/EditorTemplates`) folder. The template is then based on a single object (note also the `LabelFor()` required to create a label associated with the checkbox, and you need to delete the hidden input for `IsSelected`)

```
@model ModelViewModel

@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsSelected)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsSelected, Model.Description)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ModelId)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Description)
```

Refer also [Post an HTML Table to ADO.NET DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/post-an-html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943) to understand why your `foreach` loop would never have created the correct `name` attributes for model binding.

Then in the main view use

```
<div id="container">
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.SelectedModels)
</div>
```

and remove the hidden input for `SelectedModels` (but before you do, inspect the html for that element to understand why its `value` would never bind). The `EditorFor()` method will correctly generate the html for each item in your collection.

Next, change your `GetModels()` method to return a partial view based on `FirmwareViewModel` since that is what you will be posting back. Note that you could return a `JsonResult`, but that would mean generating a whole lot of html in the ajax call back that would not be strongly typed.

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult GetModels(string SelectedDevice)
{
    var deviceAbbreviation = _dbContext.Radios.Where(x => x.RadioName == SelectedDevice).Select(x => x.ProjectAbbreviation).FirstOrDefault();
    var models = _dbContext.AnatomyModels.Where(x => x.SerialPrefix.StartsWith(deviceAbbreviation.Trim()) && x.ParentId == 0).ToList();
    List<ModelViewModel> mvms = models.Select(x => new ModelViewModel()
    {
        ModelId = x.AnatomyModelId,
        Description = x.SerialPrefix,
        IsSelected = false, // not really necessary since its the default
    }).ToList();
    FirmwareViewModel model = new FirmwareViewModel
    {
        SelectedModels = mvms
    };
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

and your `GetModels.cshtml` view will be

```
@model FirmwareViewModel
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.SelectedModels)
```

Then, modify your ajax call to add the partial view in the success callback

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '@Url.Action("GetModels", "Firmware")', // do not need to add 3rd parameter
    data: { SelectedDevice: $('#Devices').val() },
    success: function (response) {
        $('#container').html(response);
    },
    error: function (err) {
        console.log("ERROR: " + err.responseText);
    },
})
```

The `.html()` function will replace any elements already existing in the `<div id="container">` element

Finally, since your using a view model, make use of it and do not use `ViewBag`. Your view model should contain a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Devices` property which you populate in the GET method (and use `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Device, Model.Devices, new { @class = "form-control" })` in the view (note also that the method generates `id="Device"`). It should also contain a `HttpPostedFileBase` property to avoid the additional parameter in the POST method, and allow you to add validation attributes.

Comment: Awesome, works like a charm. Thank you for the great explanation.