# jQuery.validate() error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've got a Javascript function that I call when add Ajax content to the DOM, I run `$('form').validate({  });` and Validation works for the existing and new content.

I added this script to ALL my pages thinking that it wouldn't hurt, but it does, now I have a page with a simple `form` for filtering:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Error Type", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label " })
        @Html.DropDownList("statusCodeFilter", StatusCodes, new { @class = "form-control", @OnChange = "$('#load-error-log').click();" })
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>

    <input type="submit" id="load-error-log" value="Refresh" style="display: block;" />
}
```

This will cause a Javascript error when changing the `DropDownList` option and I don't quite understand, searching online I see that duplicate IDs could be the issue, but I don't have that type of data.

> jquery.validate.js:421 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined

Can someone explain what might be happening or link to some article that I haven't come across?

Comment: Do you have more than one form in the same page? Your validation settings apply to which form?

Comment: You should not be calling `$('form').validate({  })` - that is already set up by the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` plugin. When adding new content, you need to re-parse the validator. Refer [Required field validations not working in JQuery Popup MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31768946/required-field-validations-not-working-in-jquery-popup-mvc-4/31769058#31769058)

Comment: @muecas I only have one <form> tag, this page is a ListView of an Object, the Form is the filtering.

Comment: @stephen-muecke I understand, I had the .validate() on content that would be inserted on Ajax (I will continue to do this), but don't use it on non-ajax content (regular pages).

Comment: @Derek, No! Do not do use `.validate()` - see the answer I linked to.

Comment: @stephen-muecke, I see it now, took a quick look earlier, obviously not long enough.  Is your link the same idea as this: `var form = $("form");
    form.removeData('validator');
    form.removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);`?

Comment: Yes (and in the `success` callback of your ajax call that adds the content)

Comment: How would I go about adding `ignore: false` that I used in the past (ie: `$('form').validate({ ignore: false });`), validate hidden inputs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171811/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-derek).

Answer (score -2):

you must be use **role="form"** in your form declaration

```
<form name="form" role="form">
```