# How to allow screen readers to announce ASP.NET MVC 5 form validation messages when moving focus to the field in error?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

We have an ASP.NET MVC 5 web application. We do regular accessibility testing with JAWS in conjunction with Internet Explorer 11 (enterprise mandate) and Chrome. We keep running into problems with JAWS not reading off the validation messages associated with form fields when the user TABs into the field. We use FluentValidation and the standard HTML helpers to display form fields and validation messages (example below):

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, null, new { role = "alert" })
```

A sample FluentValidation might query the database for the e-mail address in the form and show a message that "This e-mail has already been taken" which runs on the server side.

The resulting HTML sent back to the browser is:

```
<label for="Email">E-mail address:</label>

<input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" ...>

<span class="..." data-valmsg-for="Email" data-valmsg-replace="true" role="alert">
    This e-mail has already been taken
</span>
```

Nothing is associating the validation message with the form field. I always thought the MVC framework made this connection automatically, but apparently it doesn't.

According to [WebAIM](https://webaim.org/techniques/formvalidation/), we should utilize the `aria-describedby` attribute to associate form fields with inline validation errors, but to replumb the existing MVC5 framework to do that is quite the undertaking.

**How can we get screen readers to announce inline validation messages when bringing focus to a form field generated by ASP.NET MVC5 without rewriting major HTML helpers?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without creating custom `HtmlHelper` extension methods to generate the `aria-describedby` attribute in the for control, and an associated `id` attribute in the error element, you will need to use javascript to add them.

Note that each error message placeholder (generated by `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()`) is associated with its form control by the `data-valmsg-for="...."` attribute.

Assuming you want to include the `aria-describedby` for all form controls with an associated error message (and within a `<form>` element), so that its available if client side errors are added via `jquery.validate.js`, then the script (`jQuery`) will be

```
$(function () {
    // Get the form controls
    var controls = $('form').find('input, textarea, select')
        .not(':hidden, :input[type=submit], :input[type=button], :input[type=reset]');
    $.each(controls, function (index, item) {
        // Get the name of the form control
        var name = $(this).attr('name'); 
        if (!name) {
            return true;
        }
        // Get the associated error element
        var errorElement = $('[data-valmsg-for="' + name + '"]');
        if (!errorElement) {
            return true;
        }
        // Generate an id attribute based on the name of the control
        var errorId = name + "-error"
        // Add attributes to the input and the error element
        $(this).attr('aria-describedby', errorId)
        errorElement.attr('id', errorId);
    });
});
```

If you not interested in client side validation errors, then you could just use `var controls = $('.input-validation-error');` as the selector to get only form controls where a server side validation error has been added.

I would suggest including this script in an external (say) `screenreadervalidation.js` file and including it in your `jquery` or `jqueryval` bundle so that its included in all views that include forms for creating or editing data.

Comment: After playing around with things yesterday, this was basically the direction I started taking. I was actually building the `aria-describedby` on focus/focusin. I still need to test a JavaScript solution with JAWS.

Comment: We have lots of form fields that are dynamically generated via JavaScript. While the basic algorithm is sound, the DOMContentLoaded event doesn't catch these new fields. And the jQuery validate plugin seems to run onblur sometimes too for certain fields. And I have JavaScript setting focus to new newly generated fields. Oh what a tangled web I've weaved...

Comment: If you are dynamically adding new form controls, then you just need to add the relevant `class` and `id` attributes - but you did not note that in your question, and have not shown how you are adding them so impossible to include the code for that.

Comment: jQuery validation is 'lazy' and is triggered on `.blur()` and thereafter on `'.keyup()` (and I assume you are reparsing the `$.validator` when adding the new elements to the DOM? - refer [Required field validations not working in JQuery Popup MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31768946/required-field-validations-not-working-in-jquery-popup-mvc-4/31769058#31769058))

Comment: While we are doing some funky things with adding elements dynamically, this answer put me on the right track. Well done, sir!

Comment: The solution that worked for us was listening for the "blur" and "focus" events in the capturing phase, so jQuery didn't work because it only listens for events in the bubbling phase. But after responding to the event, the steps were exactly the same. Manually patch together the `aria-describedby` attribute with the validation messages.

Answer (score 2):

From a pure html perspective, the `aria-describedby` attribute is how you handle that.

```
<label for="Email">E-mail address:</label>
<input type="text" id="Email" aria-describedby="more_stuff">
<span id="more_stuff">
    This e-mail has already been taken
</span>
```

I'm not sure why that requires "replumbing" the framework or writing "major" helpers, but then I'm not an asp.net user.  If the framework doesn't allow you to associate a description with the field, then the framework is deficient and a feature request should be submitted to the framework.

Answer (score 0):

I use unobstrusive validation via the `data-val-*` attributes and create the spans that hold validation error messages so I can control placement.  In doing so I can also assign them an ID easily and use `aria-describedby`.  When an error occurs and the span is populated while the customer has focus on the input, then the reader finds the related span ID and reads the error that appears there.  The key piece here is `aria-describedby="NameOfCustomerError"` matches `id="NameOfCustomerError"` where the error will appear (because it is the element with `data-valmsg-for="NameOfCustomer"` indicating it shows errors automatically for that input).

```
<input data-val="true"
   data-val-required="@($"{CustomerResource.Label_Name}: {SharedResource.Validation_General}")"
   data-val-minlength-min="4"
   data-val-minlength="@CustomerResource.Validation_NameOfCustomer"
   type="text" maxlength="100"
   name="NameOfCustomer" id="NameOfCustomer"
   class="form-control" aria-describedby="NameOfCustomerError"
   placeholder="@CustomerResource.Label_Name" />

<span role="alert" id="NameOfCustomerError" class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="NameOfCustomer" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```